# Password validation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I can't seem to find the reason why the code isn't working. I tried to search for syntax errors but there's none. Upon typing pwd into the textbox, it should reveal the text "hello" however, it does not change the css.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .censor{
                filter: blur(10px);
                -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <text class="censor">Hello</text>
        <input type="password" placeholder="[Input password to reveal]" id="password" onkeyup="reveal()"/>

        <script>
            function reveal(){ 
                var pass = document.getElementById("password").value; 
                if (pass == "pwd") {
                    $(".censor").css("filter","blur(0)");
                    $(".censor").css("-webkit-filter","blur(0)");
                }else{
                    $(".censor").css("filter","blur(10px)");
                    $(".censor").css("-webkit-filter","blur(10px)");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, your code is right, did you forgot to import the jquery library?

Answer (score 0):

I just import the jQuery lib and works fine:

```js
function reveal(){ 
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value; 
        console.log(pass)
        if (pass == "pwd") {
            $(".censor").css("filter","blur(0)");
            $(".censor").css("-webkit-filter","blur(0)");
        }else{
            $(".censor").css("filter","blur(10px)");
            $(".censor").css("-webkit-filter","blur(10px)");
        }
    }
```

```css
.censor{
    filter: blur(10px);-webkit-filter:  blur(10px);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<text class="censor">Hello</text>
<input type="password" placeholder="[Input password to reveal]" id="password" onkeyup="reveal()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<span>` or `<div>` instead of `<text>` for the element

```
<body>

<span class="censor">Hello</span>
<input type="password" placeholder="[Input password to reveal]" id="password" onkeyup="reveal()"/>

<script>
    function reveal() { 
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value; 
        if (pass == "pwd") {
            $(".censor").css("filter", "blur(0)");
            $(".censor").css("-webkit-filter", "blur(0)");
        } else {
            $(".censor").css("filter", "blur(10px)");
            $(".censor").css("-webkit-filter", "blur(10px)");
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

I replaced  with  for the text element. Now, when you type "pwd" into the textbox, it should reveal the text "Hello" by removing the blur effect.